# Prefix in android style files item names

Tags: android, android-styles

I am new to android and have a question about the styles.xml file.

Each item for example this

```
<item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
```

works both with `"android:background"` and with just `"background"`.

What is the `android:` prefix there for?

Answer (score 0):

When creating your own styles, you should always extend an existing style from the framework or support library so that you maintain compatibility with platform UI styles. To extend a style, specify the style you want to extend with the parent attribute. You can then override the inherited style attributes and add new ones.

For example, you can inherit the Android platform's default text appearance and modify it as follows:

```
<style name="GreenText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
</style>
```

However, you should always inherit your core app styles from the Android Support Library.

But if you don't inherit them from the android support library then too things will work the same!

**Source:** Explanation text and code taken from: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

You can read more about Styles and Themes from the above doc, from where I took the example to explain you!